# Convert C# to VB. struggling with (array : new [] and keyword Await)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am struggling to convert the following code to VB.

C#:

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(client_Secrets, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
  GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
);
}
```

VB:

```
Using stream = New FileStream(client_Secrets, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
             New () {YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly}, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(Me.[GetType]().ToString()))
End Using
```

I have had to throw out the **await** and i just can't get the array to work the () has a blue line and says **Type expected**. This is by **New ()**

Please note i am aware of conversion tools like: 
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

These don't help with the `Array new ()` and keyword Await i have tired.

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov It is the array i am having problems with, the code converter won't help i have already done the conversion, its only the array and await key words which i am unsure of the VB equivalent

Comment: How about `New Object(){YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly}`?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå i tried new Object and got this error: Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential)'

Comment: I am Working on Visual studio 2010 and on a very old project. This may explain the await problem as per answers below.

Comment: Looks like 1) `AuthorizeAsync` returns a `Task(Of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential)` and not a `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential`. Or 2) The argument should be a `Task(Of Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential)` and not a `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential[]`.

Comment: Reasons for down votes would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim credential As UserCredential
Using stream = New FileStream(client_Secrets, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, New () {YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload}, "user", CancellationToken.None)
End Using
```

Comment: Await key word does not exist in VB, you have also added new () which is what is also not working.

Comment: @Pomster - Await certainly does exist. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156570.aspx

Comment: @Pomster - You must be targeting an older version of the .NET framework if the compiler is telling you it doesn't exist

Comment: @Pomster: An older version of VB - 'Await' only made it into the language in VS 2012 (VB 11?).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I am using Visual studio 2010 and working on a very old project, i am unsure how to Check the VB Version

Comment: @Pomster - Please remove my downvote. You did not mention that you were using an older version of Visual Studio in your original question.

Comment: @icemanind The New () does not exist in VB and was stated in the question that this one the main thing i was trying to fix. This was what the downvote was for. I have tried to remove it but it is locked in.

Comment: @Pomster - New() does exist in VB. Its not working on your's though because you are using an older version before it did exist.

Comment: @icemanind: "New" exists, but "New()" just doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

The VB equivalent is the following - there is no "New()":

```
Using stream = New FileStream(client_Secrets, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
  credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload }, "user", CancellationToken.None)
End Using
```

I don't understand why you had to omit the 'Await'.  Could you explain?

Comment: This is the error i get when await is inserted. 'Await' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: @Pomster: I see - you're using some version of VB prior to 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

```
    scopes.Add(Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly)

    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None,
                New FileDataStore("YouTubeService.VB.Sample")).Result
    End Using
```

this will work because i got it from google and adjust it to my needs